# Simple Basic Test with rspec for 1. url params 2.view variables in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I am beginner with rspec.

Case Example:

MyController:

```
def index
   id=params[:id];
   @nameTest=id+'test';
end
```

Need to test:

1. value of id
2. value of @nameTest

My code that fails:

```
it "basic test for index" do
      get :index,:id => 'myid'
      response.code.should eq("200")
      assigns(:id).should be_kind_of('myid')
      assigns(@nameTest).should be_kind_of('myidtest')
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in your test:

1. You try to test value of *id*, but *id* is local method variable and it will desappear after `index` method execution. It is impossible to test what value was assigned to local variable. Actually it does not make sense - in specs you need to test only result of the method execution (returned value, changed state etc.).
2. You check assigned value with `be_kind_of` checker. But `be_kind_of` checks that value on the left is of specified class, not the specified value. If you need to check value, then you can use `==` checker.

Correct test for your action is the following:

```
it "basic test for index" do
  get :index, :id => 'myid'

  response.code.should eq("200")

  assigns(:nameTest).should == 'myidtest'
end
```